# How to deal with no escape commas in string fields when using `store.format`='csv' in drill table

Tags: apache-drill

When using drill script to convert a set of `parquet` files to `csv`, running into problem where some of the fields have commas in them. This causes a problem because drill does not appear to automatically add any escaping `"<field>"` or `'<field>'` characters around the fields in the converted files (eg. for string values that look like "Soft-drink, Large").

The script looks like

```
/opt/mapr/drill/drill-1.11.0/bin/sqlline \
        -u jdbc:drill:zk=node001:5181,node002:5181,node003:5181 \
        -n $(tail -n+1 $basedir/src/drill-creds.txt | head -1) \
        -p $(tail -n+2 $basedir/src/drill-creds.txt | head -1) \
        --run=$sqldir
```

where the sql being run by drill looks like

```sql
alter session set `store.format`='csv';
create table dfs.myworkspace.`/path/to/csv/destination` as 
select .... 
from dfs.myworkspace.`/path/to/origin/files`
```

Does anyone have any common ways they work around this? Is there a way to add escaping characters to the converted csv files (tried checking the docs (https://drill.apache.org/docs/create-table-as-ctas/), but could find nothing related)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TSV or PSV formats or to update the delimiter symbol for CSV cells by configuring Format Plugin of your File Storage Plugin:

In Drill UI choose *Storage*, then *Update* dfs storage plugin, find *CSV* in *formats* and add ***delimiter*** property with a desired value.

```
"csv": {
  "type": "text",
  "extensions": [
    "csv2"
  ],
  "skipFirstLine": false,
  "extractHeader": true,
  "delimiter": "^"
},
```

Also please check ***escape*** property

See more: 
https://drill.apache.org/docs/text-files-csv-tsv-psv/#use-a-distributed-file-system

Comment: How to define the escape character? :(

Comment: @shzyincu
Have you checked an above link?
https://drill.apache.org/docs/text-files-csv-tsv-psv/#use-a-distributed-file-system